# jquery clone resizable draggable not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clone a resizable and draggable div, but it does not work properly...

This is my actual HTML code:

```
<div class="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div class="menuTrigger"></div>
    <ul>
        <li class="clone">Clone</li>
        <li class="remove">Remove</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my actual jQuery code:

```
function initialize(that){
    $(that).resizable({
        handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw'
    });
    $(that).draggable({
        stack: "div",
        distance: 0
    });

    $(that).find(".clone").click(function(){
        var $clone = $(this).parents('.resizable').clone();
        var offset = $(this).parents('.resizable').offset();
        $('body').append($clone);
        initialize($clone);
    });

    $(that).find(".remove").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.resizable').remove();
    });

    $(that).find(".menuTrigger").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
    });
}

$(".resizable").each(function(){
    initialize($(this));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s6tj0d95/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that calling `resizable` adds `handles` to the element you call it on. So when you clone your `resizable` element, it clones the `handles` and adds `handles` when you call resizable on cloned element, so you end up with 2 sets of handles, one of which doesn't have any behavior linked.

One way to fix this would be to remove the handles from the clone before calling resizable. Like this:

```
    $(that).find(".clone").click(function(){
        var $clone = $(this).parents('.resizable').clone();
        var offset = $(this).parents('.resizable').offset();
        $clone.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove()
        $('body').append($clone);
        initialize($clone);

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmja1fau/